# PHP: get content from first file in folder and then delete it

Tags: php, unlink

Using PHP, I want to get the content from the first file in a folder and when the content is loaded, delete the file. Here is what I have:

```
$a = opendir('./');
while (false !== ($entry = readdir($a))) {
    if($entry != '.' && $entry != '..') {
        echo $entry = file_get_contents('./'.$entry.'', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
        break; // only need the first file
        }
    }
```

The code above loads the first file in the folder and I can delete it successfully using something like

```
unlink("temp.txt");
```

So there are no permission denied errors. BUT what I need to do is delete the file by its variable name (because every filename is different). Surprisingly for me, `unlink("$entry");` or something similar does not let me delete it, instead showing a warning along with the first few lines of the content of that file. If I echo `$entry` It shows temp.txt correctly. Can someone enlighten me? What am I missing here?

(*Optional (un)related question*: If I have numeric files like 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, 10.txt... . Is there a way I could modify the code above in a way, that it does not load files like 1,10,2,3 ..., instead load it like 1,2,3,10...?)

UPDATE: 
The updated code that works (for future reference):

```
$a = opendir('./');
while (false !== ($entry = readdir($a))) {
    if($entry != '.' && $entry != '..') {
        echo $b = file_get_contents('./'.$entry.'', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
        break; // only need the first file
        }
    } 
unlink("./$entry");
```

Comment: You're overwriting `$entry` with file contents. So in cycle, after assignment, your `$entry` no longer points to a valid file location.

Comment: You try to delete `$entry` using a relative path, it should be `unlink("./$entry");`

Comment: What do you mean by *first* file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that you're overwriting `$entry` with the file contents, as such the filename is no longer valid when trying to delete it (explaining the error with the file contents).

Secondly, because you're using `FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH` you don't know exactly where the file is located, and `unlink` resolves related to the current working directory, which is most probably not `$a`.

Use `unlink($a.'/'.$entry)` and you'll be fine.

As for the unrelated question - use [`scandir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) to get all the files in the folder, then apply [`natsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) to the resulting array to sort by a 'natural sorting algorithm'. Keep in mind that a directory listing always also lists the folders `.` and `..` which you'll have to detect and skip or remove manually.

Comment: Perfectly explained both of my mistakes, so I could adjust it accordingly. Thank you so much!